# how to decode data of specific account

Tags: account-data, buffer, decode

how can i deocode the buffer data of account.

```
let pb = new PublicKey("GnAwACYKCx5LEv8QJUKvGigcix8AjnsrjLEn2Cu6UJrH")
   let a= await connection.getAccountInfo(pb)
```

Output
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Anchor (which I recommend), you can use `fetch` to decode account data easily.

If you're not using Anchor you need to specify the structure and decode it using something like [borsh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/borsh).

Here is an example

```
const schema = new Map([[Test, { kind: 'struct', fields: [['x', 'u8'], ['y', 'u64'], ['z', 'string'], ['q', [3]]] }]]);

const newValue = borsh.deserialize(schema, decoded, buffer);
```

---

[Example I wrote of decoding Metaplex Metadata](https://github.com/vicyyn/MetaplexMetadata-js/blob/main/utils.ts)